# Is there any way to set up a .bin file in my cloud vm to restart my server every time it crashes?

Tags: linux, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Title explains everything. I am currently working on a minecraft server for my school in the cloud; however it crashes frequently and I don't have enough time to restart it every time it crashes. Is there any way that I can make a file to restart it every time it crashes or better yet make it so that it can restart every night at midnight?

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to use additional VM to schedule a job (crontab) with OCI CLI restart command
The job can run every day at midnight and run the below command:

```
oci compute instance action --instance-id ocid.xxx --action SOFTRESET
```

or

```
oci compute instance action --instance-id ocid.xxx --action RESET
```

For your info

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alarm for your VM and trigger code to restart your VM. Here are the steps:

1. Write a Function to restart your VM instance.
2. Create an alarm to monitor the health of your VM instance.
3. Configure the alarm to cause your Function to run when the alarm fires.

Here is an example of how to write a Function to resize a VM in the event that the memory usage of the VM has breached a predefined threshold
https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Notification/Tasks/scenarioa.htm

You can refer to the example above and modify the following:

1. In your Function code, replace the `compute_client.update_instance` (resize VM) method with the [instance_action](https://oracle-cloud-infrastructure-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/core/client/oci.core.ComputeClient.html#oci.core.ComputeClient.instance_action) (**restart** VM) method.
2. Create an alarm to your VM instance with the following alarm properties:

> ```
> Metric namespace: oci_computer_infrastructure_health
> Metric name: instance_status
> Dimension name: resourceId
> Trigger rule: Operator:greater than, Value:0 (any value > 0 means that the VM instance is unhealthy)
> ```

**Note: The restart VM Function code sample uses the OCI Python SDK. You have the option to use other [supported language SDKs](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/sdks.htm).